# How to get an image link from a JSON to render in a react app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web-deployment

new to react here. As the title says, I have a JSON that has data in it that I am trying to render. Everything is showing except for the pictures. How can I make them show. Here is my code:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import './App.css';

function App() {
  const [users, setUsers] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch('https://reqres.in/api/users')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(resData => setUsers(resData.data))
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <table>
        <tbody>
        {
          users.map((user, index) => 
           <tr key={index}>
             <td>{user.first_name}</td>
             <td>{user.last_name}</td>
             <td>{user.email}</td>
             <td>{user.avatar}</td>
           </tr>
          )
        }
        </tbody>
      </table>
     </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

The end result should be like this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/nN1JX.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an img tag to render user avatar,

```js
 <td>
  <img src={user.avatar} />
 </td>
```

Answer (score 1):

As you need to render the link as an image you should use img tag.

```
<img src={user.avatar} alt=""/>
```

If you need to set width or height, you can do as follows.

```
<img src={user.avatar} alt="" width="200px"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to use img and `{user.avatar}` will return image url, so if you have a link of img, instead of directly using it in `<td>` tag use it like -

`<td><img src={user.avatar} alt="text" /></td>`

as you want to use img so you must need to use `<img>` tag .

Comment: Great Answer @Mishra Vaibhav, however the value for the `src` attribute of the `img` element would need to be encapsulated in double quotes. I'm not a react expert and was asked to review your answer as part of stack overflow's review process since this is your first answer on the platform (Congrats). Could you confirm that when react renders this element that the `src` attribute's value will be encapsulated in double quotes?

Comment: @Oxymoron when u use `{user.avatar}` it will give you link by default in double quotes and if you use it as `{"user.avatar"}` then it will consider it as a string not any json img link that's why we didn't used " " here.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you for the follow up. Great answer!

Answer (score -1):

you can use

```
<image
source={{ uri: user.avatar }}/>
```

If the image doesn't show,
you can input styling height and width with stylesheet

```
<image
style={styles.image}
source={{ uri: user.avatar }} /> 

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
image:{
height: 80,
widht: 80,
},
});
```

Comment: There is no `image` element. And there isn't a `source` attribute on `img`.